# Loop to check all 14 days in the pay period

Tags: oracle, function, loops, plsql

Name: Calc_Anniversary

Input: Pay_Date, Hire_Date, Termination_Date

Output: "Y" if is the anniversary of the employee's Hire_Date, "N" if it is not, and "T" if he has been terminated before his anniversary.

Description: Create local variables to hold the month and day of the employee's Date_of_Hire, Termination_Date, and of the processing date using the TO_CHAR function. First check to see if he was terminated before his anniversary. The anniversary could be on any day during the pay period, so there will be a loop to check all 14 days in the pay period to see if one was his anniversary.

```
  CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Calc_anniversary(
   incoming_anniversary_date IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN BOOLEAN
   IS
 hiredate        VARCHAR2(20);
 terminationdate VARCHAR(20);
 employeeid      VARCHAR2(38);
 paydate         NUMBER := 0;
 BEGIN
SELECT Count(arndt_raw_time_sheet_data.pay_date)
INTO   paydate
FROM   arndt_raw_time_sheet_data
WHERE paydate = incoming_anniversary_date;

WHILE paydate <= 14 LOOP
    SELECT To_char(employee_id, '999'),
           To_char(hire_date, 'DD-MON'),
           To_char(termination_date, 'DD-MON')
    INTO   employeeid, hiredate, terminationdate
    FROM   employees,
           time_sheet
    WHERE  employees.employee_id = time_sheet.employee_id
           AND paydate = pay_date;

    IF terminationdate > hiredate THEN
      RETURN 'T';
    ELSE
      IF To_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON') = To_char(hiredate, 'DD-MON')THEN
        RETURN 'Y';
      ELSE
        RETURN 'N';
      END IF;
    END IF;

    paydate := paydate + 1;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Tables I am using

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(15),
 LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25),
 ADDRESS_LINE_ONE VARCHAR2(35),
 ADDRESS_LINE_TWO VARCHAR2(35),
 CITY VARCHAR2(28),
 STATE CHAR(2),
 ZIP_CODE CHAR(10),
 COUNTY VARCHAR2(10),
 EMAIL VARCHAR2(16),
 PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(12),
 SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER VARCHAR2(11),
 HIRE_DATE DATE,
 TERMINATION_DATE DATE,
 DATE_OF_BIRTH DATE,
 SPOUSE_ID INTEGER,
 MARITAL_STATUS CHAR(1),
  ALLOWANCES INTEGER,
  PERSONAL_TIME_OFF FLOAT,
  CONSTRAINT pk_employee_id PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_spouse_id FOREIGN KEY (SPOUSE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMPLOYEE_ID))
 /
 CREATE TABLE Arndt_Raw_Time_Sheet_data ( EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER,
    PAY_DATE DATE,
     HOURS_WORKED FLOAT,
     SALES_AMOUNT FLOAT,
      CONSTRAINT pk_employee_id_pay_date_time PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID, PAY_DATE),
      CONSTRAINT fk_employee_id_time FOREIGN KEY (EMPLOYEE_ID) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES (EMployee_ID));
```

error **FUNCTION Calc_Anniversary compiled

Warning: execution completed with warning**

Comment: If only you had a programming question

Comment: need help getting in the right direction creating the loop for this function thanks

Comment: West give you the best feng shui

Comment: is the homework tag deprecated?

Comment: @Rachel, seriously, make an effort.  Show an error, or unexpected output and what you've tried.  Don't just throw down some code and say "doesn't work".

Comment: I have been working on this.. when I run the function...FUNCTION Calc_Anniversary compiled
Warning: execution completed with warning

Comment: I really think it is my loop.. because i have done it is declare also

Answer (score 1):

Functions have to return something.  It is normal for the RETURN statement to be the last statement in a function.

You have chosen not to do this, and that's why you're getting an error.  All your RETURN statements are embedded in conditional branches, so if your logic never executes the loop you will never execute a RETURN.

Your loop logic is confused.  You are populating your `paydate` as a count (so why is it called ""paydate"?) but your initialisation query compares 'paydate' to your parameter  `incoming_anniversary_date` which is a date.  Perhaps you meant to compare it to the tabel column `pay_date`?  So who knows what your code is actually doing?

Anyway, the most important thing is to introduce some best practice into your function: you need to populate a variable and restrict yourself to just the one RETURN statement.

```
   return_value char(1);

 BEGIN
     return_value := 'X';
     ....   
    WHILE paydate <= 14 LOOP
    ....
    IF terminationdate > hiredate THEN
         return_value :=  'T';
    ELSE
      IF To_char(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON') = To_char(hiredate, 'DD-MON')THEN
        return_value :=   'Y';
      ELSE
        return_value :=  'N';
      END IF;
    END IF;
       ...
  END LOOP;
  RETURN return_value;
END;
```

---

Also, this is wrong:

```
IF terminationdate > hiredate THEN
```

You converted those dates to strings, which means that '23-JAN' > '22-DEC'.  This is probably not the result you intend.

Oh, and rename your variable `paydate` to something a bit less confusing, like `l_count`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 create or replace
 FUNCTION Calc_Anniversary(employee IN VARCHAR2)
 RETURN VARCHAR2

 IS

 counter INTEGER;
 term_date VARCHAR2(15);
  h_date VARCHAR2(15);
  p_date DATE;

  BEGIN

    SELECT TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'DD-MON'), TO_CHAR(termination_date, 'DD-MON'), pay_date INTO h_date, term_date, p_date
   FROM employees e, diaz_raw_time_sheet_data d
   WHERE e.employee_id = d.employee_id
   AND e.employee_id = employee;

FOR counter IN 0 .. 14 LOOP 
  IF term_date > h_date THEN
  RETURN 'T';
  ELSIF TO_CHAR(p_date,'DD-MON') = h_date THEN
  RETURN 'Y';
  END IF;
  p_date := p_date - 1;
END LOOP;
 IF h_date <> TO_CHAR(p_date, 'DD-MON') THEN
RETURN 'N';
 END IF;
 END;
```

Comment: I guess I have my functions input wrong should be pay_date, hire_date, and termination_date